# USING Filter in a Nested FOREACH in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have two pig relations. The first one `count_pairs` shows pairs of words and how many times they were seen. ex `((car,tire), 4)`. The second is `word_counts`, which keeps track of how many times each word was seen ex. `(car, 20)`. I would like to find the percentage of how many times each pair was seen compared to how many times just the first word was seen. In our case I would want `((car,tire), 4/20)`. I tried to write a nested foreach to solve this problem :

```
> percent_count_pairs = FOREACH count_pairs {
> denom = FILTER word_counts BY ($0 ==count_pairs.pair.word1);
> GENERATE pair, count2/(double)denom.$1;}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
'Pig script failed to parse: 
<file src/cluster.pig, line 27, column 15> expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)'
```

This point to the line with the `FILTER`; 
googling this error did not lead me to anything helpful. Please help! 
(ps. this does work if I take the line with `FILTER` out of the foreach...)

Comment: Couldn't you have achieved the same thing with a ORDER and LIMIT command?

Answer (score 2):

After more googling I came to realize that this is a bug in Pig that will not allow  this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1798. I ended up writing my own UDF to filter.

Comment: Cool nested FOREACH solution, I am also curious, have you tried a JOIN? e.g. something like: pairs_word_counts = 
    JOIN word_counts BY word, count_pairs BY pair.word1;

pair_ratio =
    FOREACH pairs_word_counts
    GENERATE
        count_pairs::pair,
        count_pairs::pair.count / word_counts::count;