# How to do condition JOIN in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I have two relation A,B

```
DESCIBE A
A:{ip_num:long,data:int}

DESCIBE B
B:{ip_start_num:long,ip_end_num:long}
```

I want to have the product:

```
C:{group:(ip_start_num:long, ip_end_num:long), B:{(ip_num:long, data:int)}}

where ip_num >ip_start_num && ip_num < ip_end_num
```

is it any possibility to do with PigLatin?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a `FILTER` operation inside a nested `FOREACH` however; it seems like there is a bug, so that such a sentence won't even parse. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1798. This post also refers to the same issue. [USING Filter in a Nested FOREACH in PIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235236/using-filter-in-a-nested-foreach-in-pig)

I came across the same problem yesterday and there were two solutions available: the first one is to write an UDF to do the filtering by ip range. The second is to find the way of doing a simple join between the two relations so that you could have this other relation:

`D:{ip_num:long,data:int,ip_start_num:long,ip_end_num:long}`.

There you could filter without the nested foreach. I went with the second choice, however it is not always a way to do the join.

Answer (score 0):

No theta-joins in Pig I'm afraid.  You can do a cross join followed by a filter.  Be wary of the resulting data explosion.