# Pig Latin (Filter 2nd data source in foreach loop)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 2 data sources. One contains a list of api calls and the other contains all related authentication events. There can be multiple Auth Events for each Api Call, I want to find the auth event that:
a) contains the same "identifier" as the Api Call
b) happened within a second after the Api Call
c) is the closest to the Api Call after the above filtering.

I had planned to loop through each ApiCall event in a foreach loop and then use filter statements on the authevents to find the correct one - however, it does not appear that this is possible ([USING Filter in a Nested FOREACH in PIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235236/using-filter-in-a-nested-foreach-in-pig))

Would anyone be able to suggest other ways to achieve this. If it helps, here's the Pig script I tried to use:

```
apiRequests = LOAD '/Documents/ApiRequests.txt' AS (api_fileName:chararray, api_requestTime:long, api_timeFromLog:chararray, api_call:chararray, api_leadString:chararray, api_xmlPayload:chararray, api_sourceIp:chararray, api_username:chararray, api_identifier:chararray);
authEvents = LOAD '/Documents/AuthEvents.txt' AS (auth_fileName:chararray, auth_requestTime:long, auth_timeFromLog:chararray, auth_call:chararray, auth_leadString:chararray, auth_xmlPayload:chararray, auth_sourceIp:chararray, auth_username:chararray, auth_identifier:chararray);
specificApiCall = FILTER apiRequests BY api_call == 'CSGetUser';                 -- Get all events for this specific call
match = foreach specificApiCall {                                                -- Now try to get the closest mathcing auth event
        filtered1 = filter authEvents by auth_identifier == api_identifier;      -- Only use auth events that have the same identifier (this will return several)
        filtered2 = filter filtered1 by (auth_requestTime-api_requestTime)<1000; -- Further refine by usings auth events within a second on the api call's tiime
        sorted = order filtered2 by auth_requestTime;                            -- Get the auth event that's closest to the api call
        limited = limit sorted 1;
        generate limited;
        };
dump match;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `FOREACH` is not for working with a second relation while looping over the first one.  It's for when your relation has a bag in it and you want to work with that bag as though it were its own relation.  You cannot work with `apiRequests` and `authEvents` at the same time unless you do some kind of joining or grouping first to put all the information you need into a single relation.

Your task works nicely conceptually with a `JOIN` and `FILTER`, if you did not need to limit yourself to a single authorization event:

```
allPairs = JOIN specificApiCall BY api_identifier, authEvents BY auth_identifier;
match = FILTER allPairs BY (auth_requestTime-api_requestTime)<1000;
```

Now all the information is together, and you could do `GROUP match BY api_identifier` followed by a nested `FOREACH` to pick out a single event.

However, you could do this in a single step if you use the `COGROUP` operator, which is like `JOIN` but without the cross-product -- you get two bags with the grouped records from each relation.  Use this to pick out the nearest authorization event:

```
cogrp = COGROUP specificApiCall BY api_identifier, authEvents BY auth_identifier;
singleAuth = FOREACH cogrp {
    auth_sorted = ORDER authEvents BY auth_requestTime;
    auth_1 = LIMIT auth_sorted 1;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(specificApiCall), FLATTEN(auth_1);
    };
```

Then `FILTER` to only leave the ones within 1 second:

```
match = FILTER singleAuth BY (auth_requestTime-api_requestTime)<1000;
```

Comment: Thanks Winnie, I used COGROUP and it worked a treat. You're the best!