# In hadoop ecosystem, I am using Pig and got stuck in following query?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

```
country_landmass_sorted = foreach country_landmass {
country_landmass_count = foreach country generate group,COUNT(name) as r;
sorted  = ORDER country_landmass_count BY $1 DESC;
GENERATE group, sorted;
};
```

I got the following error. How to resolve this error?

```
2016-03-25 22:19:33,519 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 11, column 16> expression is not a project expression: (Name: ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1458968172221.log
```

Comment: check if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235236/using-filter-in-a-nested-foreach-in-pig..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it up, use FOREACH for generating count and then a normal expression for ORDER BY. Try this.

```
A = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',') as (a:chararray,b:int);
B = group A BY a;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,COUNT(A.a);
D = ORDER C By $1;
```

Comment: Can't we do in one query using nested?

Comment: You can have only one generate at the end of the nested foreach, so you cannot apply two generate for Statement 3 and 4.